# How receive data with C in Windows via BLE5

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can receive data via Python with the bleak library, but it works slowly

Now I totally can not understand how to receive data in C language in Windows, I found this library that called simple BLE https://github.com/OpenBluetoothToolbox/SimpleBLE in fact not so simple and for Linux Bluz.

Answer (score 1):

You use Windows's BLE API, which you can find at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-low-energy-overview.

These APIs are based on "Windows Runtime API", which is available from a wide range of languages. I would recomend C++ instead of C. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt.

Comment: looks good, but only for C#

Comment: No, it is no only for c#, it can be used with c++ as well. Or you can use thrid party libraries.

Comment: Some examples can be found here for enumerating devices in the cppwinrt folder: https://github.com/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing.